# SaveAs with value from another open workbook

Tags: excel, vba

This code saves the file with the date format.

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
  "Path\" & _
  "Customer PHR % " & Format(Date - 1, "mm-dd-yyyy")
```

I want to add to the file name a percentage that exists in another open workbook.
The workbook is called *Master Automatic.xlsm*, and the sheet name is *DSP*, and the value in cell *H3*.

I tried this.

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
  "Path\" & _
  "Customer PHR % " & Workbooks("Master Automatic.xlsm").Worksheets("DSP").Range("H3") & Format(Date - 1, "mm-dd-yyyy")
```

The file name should look like *Customer PHR 12-11-2023 97.54%*

Comment: What file name do you get? What is wrong?

Comment: I doubt that the first option works as path is written in quotation marks - which will definitly return an invalid filename due to the backslash

Comment: Instead of saying "but not working" explain exactly what happens, including the wording of any error message shown

Answer (score 0):

You might need to define `percentage` as a variable, to `SaveAs` for the file name, try below (you may just need part of the script), hope it works.

```vb
Dim percentage As String
Dim wb_master As Workbook

On Error Resume Next
Set wb_master = Workbooks("Master Automatic.xlsm")
On Error GoTo 0

If wb_master Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Master Automatic workbook is invalid."
    Exit Sub
End If

percentage = wb_master.Worksheets("DSP").Range("H3").Value

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "Path\" & _
    "Customer PHR " & Format(Date - 1, "mm-dd-yyyy") & " " & percentage & "%"
```